# With OOP, when you have an instance of a class as attribute of another class, how is it possible to instantiate it only in the 2nd class?

Tags: c++, oop

Their is something I don't understand with OOP : when you have an instance of a class as attribute of another class, how is it possible to instantiate it only in the constructor of the 2nd class?

For example in this example I would like to instantiate the class Foo in Bar's constructor. How should I modify my code so it work?

Foo.h

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int x, y;

public:
    Foo(int a, int b);
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"

Foo::Foo(int a, int b)
{
    x = a;
    y = b;
}
```

Bar.h

```
#include "Foo.h"

class Bar
{
private:
    Foo foo;

public:
    Bar();
};
```

Bar.cpp

```
#include "Bar.h"

Bar::Bar()
{
}
```

Comment: `Bar::Bar() : foo(1, 2) {}`

Comment: Look specifically at the part right after the word "Furthermore" in the accepted answer to the question LogicStuff suggested this question duplicates.

Comment: I have some more extra questions, that's why I didn't accepted any answer right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Foo` needs to be constructed from 2 parameters you are either going to have to have the user pass them to `Bar`s constructor and create it with them or just use some hard coded values.  I would suggest getting them from the user but also have a default value for the parameters so it acts as a default constructor.

```
class Bar
{
private:
    Foo foo;

public:
    Bar(int a = 0, int b = 0) : foo(a, b) {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.
What if I have a Foo foo[3]; ?
Would it be :
      Bar(int a = 0, int b = 0) : foo[0](a, b), foo[1](a, b), foo[2](a, b) {}

Comment: @LukeImYourFather see this example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d867a927236d786a

Comment: I get then error "cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays"

Comment: @LukeImYourFather You need to compile with C++11 or above for it to work.